# Mysql Select rows based on whether other column is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a legacty table "wages" that I cannot change and I want to get results from this table such that i get allowedWage for a country based on whether there is a value for farmer or not otherwise get the allowedWage for worker

Input

```
id    country farmer worker allowedWage
1     US      1      null   100
2     US      null   1      50
3     AU      1      null   60
4     CA      null   1      80
```

Expected Output

```
  id country allowedWage
   1  US      100
   3  AU      60
   4  CA      80
```

so I wrote the following query if someone wants to find the wage for country US, AU, CA and IN

```
    select id, country, allowedWage from wages 
where country in ('US', 'AU', 'CA', 'IN') 
and ((farmer = 1 and worker is null) or (worker = 1 or farmer is null))
```

but this obviously gives all row and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to exclude worker data for a country if there is value of farmer

Actual Output

```
  id country allowedWage
   1  US      100
   2  US      50 
   3  AU      60
   4  CA      80
```

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT country,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN farmer THEN allowedWage END), MAX(allowedWage)) allowedWage
FROM wages 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

For MySql 8.0+ you can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country,
       FIRST_VALUE(allowedWage) OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY farmer = 1 DESC) allowedWage
FROM wages
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9eeb1edaecd0e7ef8c78ead998fd4ad6).
Results:

```
> country | allowedWage
> :------ | ----------:
> AU      |          60
> CA      |          80
> US      |         100
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is the closest answer*especially the first query since we are having mysql version 5.6) that I can get to. Although since its group by you could never figure out if the wage is of farmer or worker. If I had that then this answer would have been perfect. If I dont find a better answer in a day, I am marking this as my desired answer. Anyway upvoting as of now

Comment: @SandeepNair In your expected output there is no column that indicates whether the wage is of farmer or worker. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a6b0cda73d00d261508ff11e421097a

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . this a prioritization query.  You can use `not exists` to select the workers where necessary:

```
select id, country, allowedWage
from t
where farmer = 1 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.country = t.country and t2.farmer = 1
                 );
```

Note that the `worker` column doesn't seem necessary because all the information needed is in the `farmer` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()`, if you are running MySQL 8.0.

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by country order by (farmer <=> 1) desc) rn
    from mytable t
)
where rn = 1
```